# wavetables implemented on iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I just saw an iPhone app which uses wavetables to generate sounds. I wish to know how it is possible to implement.
I am pretty much sure that core audio have to be used, but any other idea where to go for some other info will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After huge investigating I have found an open source project regarding this. http://gitorious.org/pdlib/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want CoreAudio or AudioUnits for a *responsive* program (e.g. AudioQueue's latency is a bit high).

You'll want AudioFile APIs (in AudioToolbox) for reading the tables if you save them as a common audio file format (just wave files with a new shape every cycle, which is every N samples).

Beyond that, you'll probably have to write the wavetable engine. I have done that; It's not tough if you know how wavetable synthesis works and are familiar with audio signals. It's one of the most basic synthesis types.

[musicdsp.org](http://www.musicdsp.org) *may* have something you can use as a starting point for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial on how to use the STK: http://arielelkin.github.io/articles/mandolin/

It is an open-source C++ library with cool synths, some with wavetables.

Answer (score 0):

Audio file I/O: I found a great resource [here](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex3). This guy created an excellent API for using ExtAudioFileServices.

A must read is [Learning Core Audio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848). Chris Adamson and company have really put together a great resource. Chris's blog can also be found [here](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/)

Also, sign up for the Core Audio mailing list.

Michael Tyson's blog/ resources are great too [A Tasty Pixel](http://atastypixel.com/).

Hope this helps!